# Codeigniter - mysql query with variable

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need help for the query in my model, I want to find the field with variable that i'm input to the controller and as for right now the problem is that the field won't read my variable so here is the code

**Controller**

```
public function tampil_soal(){
        $kode_soal = $this->input->post('kode_soal');
        $where = array('kode_soal' => $kode_soal);
        $data['tampilan']= $this->m_model->tampil_soal($kode_soal)->result();
        $this->load->view('soal_tampil',$data);
    }
```

**Model**

```
public function tampil_soal($where){
        return $this->db->query("select * from soal where kode_soal='$where' ORDER BY RAND()");
    }
```

**View**

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url()?>siswa/tampil_soal" method="post" class="form">
    <input class="input" name="kode_ujian" placeholder="Kode ujian"/>
  <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Selesai"/>
</form>
```

Comment: You are passing `$where` as an array, while you are not using the key's value for using it as a column in `Where` condition

Comment: Your code is open to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/2469308) related attacks. Please learn to use [Prepared Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Have you check $kode_soal get value in controller?

Comment: @Sachin yes i'm already make the view input of the `$kode_soal` and make sure that it gets the value to the controller but the problem is probably in the model?
@MadhurBhaiya what do you mean that is open to SQL injection? is like get easily hacked or something?

Comment: can you try echo $this->db->last_query(); so we can find your query is correct or something wrong with query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**View**

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url()?>siswa/tampil_soal" method="post" class="form">
    <input class="input" name="kode_ujian" placeholder="Kode ujian"/>
  <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Selesai"/>
</form>
```

**Controller**

you are using wrong post name "$this->input->post('kode_soal')" change this to $this->input->post('kode_ujian') 
 then

```
public function tampil_soal(){
        $kode_soal = $this->input->post('kode_ujian');
        $where = array('kode_soal' => $kode_soal);
        $data['tampilan']= $this->m_model->tampil_soal($kode_soal);
        $this->load->view('test',$data);
    }
```

**Model**

```
public function tampil_soal($where){
    $qry = $this->db->query("select * from soal where kode_soal='$where' ORDER BY RAND()");
        if($qry->num_rows()>0){
            return $qry->result();
        }else{
            return array();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

just try this:

```
//controller
public function tampil_soal(){
    $kode_soal = $this->input->post('kode_ujian');
    $data['tampilan']= $this->m_model->tampil_soal($kode_soal);
    $this->load->view('soal_tampil',$data);
}


// model
public function tampil_soal($where){
    $this->db->where('kode_soal',$where);
    return $this->db->get('soal')->result();
    // use the return $this->db->get('soal')->row();
    // if your query return one record
}
```

Comment: i'm sorry i don't quite understand what you are saying

Comment: you used the wrong input name in your controller and I made it correct in code above use the above code it will work

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use result() function with query

```
public function tampil_soal($where){
        return $this->db->query("select * from soal where kode_soal='$where' ORDER BY RAND()")->result();
    }
```

Comment: isn't the `->result()` is for the controller? PS:I have tried it still not working, and it says `Call to a member function result() on a non-object`

Answer (score 0):

try this query:
//controller

```
public function tampil_soal(){
        $data['tampilan']= $this->m_model->tampil_soal($this->input->post('kode_soal');
        $this->load->view('soal_tampil',$data);
    }
```

//model

```
public function tampil_soal($where){
      return $this->db->where('kode_soal',$where)->get('soal')->result();
    }
```

Comment: You didn't add the `$where` on the controller

Comment: or is there another way get the `$where` from the model?

Comment: is kode_soal field exists in your datatable?

Answer (score 0):

**Model**

```
public function tampil_soal($where){
    $condition = $where;
    // Your Condition...
    $this->db->where($condition);
    // Order By ...
    $this->db->order_by('RAND()');
    // Return Data from Table ...
    return $this->db->get('soal');    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
public function tampil_soal($where){
        return $this->db->query("select * from soal where kode_soal='$where' ORDER BY RAND()");
    }
```

to this

```
public function tampil_soal($kode_soal){
        return $this->db->query("select * from soal where kode_soal='$kode_soal' ORDER BY RAND()");
    }
```

hope it'll helps